# Redshift SQL SUM over fixed number days

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm currently stucked on an issue. I have daily data and I want to SUM all the data for the next 30 days over a year.

| Date | Views |
| --- | --- |
| 28-01-2021 | 1 |
| 29-01-2021 | 5 |
| 30-01-2021 | 1 |
| 31-01-2021 | 5 |

And I want to have the number of views starting the 28th for the next 30 days, then the next 30 days  etc... over a year (or twelve times)

So basically what I want to see is something like this, Series being the series of 30 days (first 30 days, second 30 days etc...)

| Series | Views |
| --- | --- |
| 1 (from 28-01 to 28-02) | 250 |
| 2 (from 01-03 to 30-03) | 200 |
| 3 (from 31-04 to 29-04) | 300 |
| 4 (from 30-04 to 29-05) | 550 |

Thank you if anyone can help.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have one row for each day, you can use a window function:

```
select t.*,
       sum(views) over (order by date
                        rows between current row and 29 following
                       ) as views_30days
from t;
```

Note:  This interprets "next 30 days" as really being "today plus the next 29 days".  If you don't want the current day, then the window frame would be:

```
                        rows between 1 following and 29 following
```

Comment: Thank you I'll try using that but I don't want my days to overlap. It really is a series. I added an example, sorry if I wasn't clear)